# How do I use Sessions with Custom User Model using Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, session, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-sessions

I am currently working on a project which involves using Django solely for Back-end API endpoints using class-based views to authenticate and serve database content to users on the Front-end.

```
class UserLogin(APIView): # User Login
def post(self, request, format=None):
    print(request)
    try:
        User_Cred.objects.get(username=request.data['username'], password=request.data['password']) # Retrieves user record
        pass # TEMPORARY

    except User_Cred.DoesNotExist: # If User Record does not exist,
        raise Http404
```

Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to implement sessions for user authentication. I know that Django has some sort of integration with sessions. However, I am not using Django's default user model but a custom one instead (see below).

```
class Users(models.Model):
username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

Is there any way I can use my custom user model for session authentication? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a custom User model you simply have to add this line to your `settings.py`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "your_app_name.Users"
```

Then for your permissions and authentication system, you can follow this doc to set it up:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading the docs and I see a few mentions of something called "AbstractUser" from django.contrib.auth.models. I'm having trouble understanding how to use it and where the code should go

Comment: Okay I've gained a better understanding of how to create custom models now. But, How would I go about storing these users in a MySQL table?

Comment: You should go through Django's official tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/